# Number of arguments in a ruby block

Tags: ruby, lambda

I'm new to Ruby, but not to languages that allow lambda's, such as groovy. So I saw this example:

```
myArray.product(otherArray).reject{|i,j| i > j}
```

in a ruby code block, and I hadn't seen this block take 2 arguments before, but when I went to look at the [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-reject) I can only see the documentation that says that it takes 1 argument. I looked at the same for the `enumerable` class, but that doc only shows 1 argument also.

I understand that it works, I guess I was hoping that there was an easier way to determine how many arguments it takes other then a guess and test method. How can I tell how many arguments a block takes in Ruby?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This works because Ruby supports destructuring.

> Destructuring allows you to bind a set of variables to a corresponding set of values anywhere that you can normally bind a value to a single variable.

This allows the following to hold true:

```
arr = [1, 2]
x = arr
x == [1, 2] # true

y, z = arr
y == 1 # true
z == 2 # true
```

You can see from the following code that destructuring in arguments to blocks isn't unique to the built-in methods that take a block:

```
def my_method(arr)
  yield arr
end

my_method([1, 2, 3]) {|x| puts x.inspect }
# => [1, 2, 3]
my_method([1, 2, 3]) {|x, y, z| puts x.inspect }
# => 1
```

Check out [Destructuring with Ruby](http://tony.pitluga.com/2011/08/08/destructuring-with-ruby.html) for more information.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking, explains what I was not understanding, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can do some interesting restructuring in block parameters, depending on the structure of your array:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]].reject {|x,y| y == 8 }
#=> [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

You can group them in parentheses:

```
[ [[1,2],3], [[1,3],6] ].select {|(x,y),z| x == 1 && z == 3 }
#=> [ [[1,2],3] ]
```

You can also use the splat operator for various things, like dealing with variable-length subarrays:

```
[[:a,:b,2,3,4,5,6], [:c,:d,7,8,9]].each {|x,y,*numbers| puts numbers.inspect }
#=> [2,3,4,5,6]
#=> [7,8,9]
```

Comment: While this demonstrates some neat examples, my question was more pointed towards how to be able to tell what works as an argument for the block, IE when the `reject` method takes the block, how can you tell what arguments is it passing it.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby is flexible in how it interprets the arguments; here is a similar example, with one and then two arguments:

```
[1, 3].product([2, 4]).reject {|a| a.first > a.last }
=> [[1, 2], [1, 4], [3, 4]] 
[1, 3].product([2, 4]).reject {|a,b| a > b }
=> [[1, 2], [1, 4], [3, 4]]
```

The rule of thumb here is that you can treat the arguments either as a composite object, or as individual elements in a collection. E.g.,

```
[1, 2, 3].tap {|a,b,c| puts [a,b,c].inspect }
[1, 2, 3]
... 
[1, 2, 3].tap {|a,b| puts [a,b].inspect }
[1, 2]
... 
[1, 2, 3].tap {|a| puts a.inspect }
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: I understand that it works, I guess I was hoping that there was an easier way to determine how many arguments it takes other then a guess and test method.

Comment: Most are fairly flexible, but generally default to one argument. When in doubt, look at the docs. There are some that generally take two, like Hash enumeration, that yield a two-element array when used with a single block parameter (e.g. `{:a => 1, :b => 2}.each {|x| ... }` uses `[:a,1]` and `[:b,2]`).

Comment: As I linked, the doc for what I was giving an example, Array.reject, only shows one argument, while the code shows either 1 or 2.

Comment: @Nicholas: `#reject` is just accepting a block argument.  It is the behavior of blocks that is relevant here rather than `#reject`.  It is the block that is unpacking the arguments, or not, as the case may be.